# Geometric Properties of Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

This question arises from [following former thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289750/geometrically-reduced-implies-reduced-resp-geom-integral-irreducible) of mine and refers to a remark from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry"  at page 90:

[image]

In remark 3.2.11 is stated if $X$ is an algebraic variety over field $k$ and it's base change $X_{\overline{k}}= X_{Spec(k)}Spec(\bar{k})$ wrt algebraic closure $k \subset \overline{k}$ verifies one of the properties ***reduced, connected, or
irreducible***, then ***Lemma 2.6*** says that then $X_K$ verifies the same property for any algebraic extension $K/k$.

Here the lemma 2.6:

[image]

My QUESTION is how the author concretely deduces remark 3.1.12 ***with help of 2.6***?

I know that there are some ways to deduce the remark 3.2.11 ***without*** using explicitely Lemma 2.6 (see for example the comments of @user45878 in the linked thread).

But the main point of this question that makes me curious is concretely ***which role does lemma 2.6 in the proof?*** It seems quite redundant to me to consider a intermediate field $K'$ between algebraic extension $K/k$ having properties as stated.

Indeed:

Firstly, the "reduced" property is local so assume $X=Spec(A)$ and assume $A \otimes_k \bar{k}$ reduced. Assume, $K/k$ is an arbitrary algebraic extension of $k$. Then, since $A$ is a flat $k$-module we have the  inclusion $A \otimes_k K \subset A \otimes_k \bar{k}$. So $A \otimes_k K$ reduced. So no usage of Lemma 2.6.

In case of ***irreducibility*** assume that $X_{\overline{k}}$ is irreducible but $X_K$ not. Wlog $X_K= X^1 \cup X^2$. Base change by $\bar{k}/K$ gives at least two irreducible components $X_{\bar{k}}= X^1 _{\bar{k}} \cup X^2 _{\bar{k}}$ (since $X^i _{\bar{k}}$ could after base change become also reducible). But nevertheless we obtain a contradiction to irreducibility of $X_{\overline{k}}$. For "connectness" the argument is similar.

And now the question agian, where do we here really need 2.6?

What do I oversee?

Or does anybody see what Liu had by usage of 2.6 in mind?

Comment: I don't know what Liu has in mind. For any algebraic extension $k \subset K \subset \bar{k}$ we have that $X_{\bar{k}} \to X_{K}$ is a surjective morphism as it is the base change of a surjective morphism (so it remains surjective). Now the image of any connected/irreducible topological space under a continous map is connnected/irreducible. It doesn't getting any simpler than this. Now to prove that $X_{K}$ is reduced, your argument is exactly the same Liu uses to prove Lemma $2.6$. I would suggest not to get caught up in these sort of things.

Comment: Also, why is $(X^1 \cup X^2)_{\bar{k}} =X_{\bar{k}}^1 \cup X_{\bar{k}}^2$? This is an  incorrect implication.

Comment: Both $X^1$ and $X^2$ are only topological spaces. A priori they don't have any scheme structure on them (though it is possible to give any closed subset of a scheme a scheme structure). So I don't know what you mean by taking their base change when they are just topological spaces.

Comment: @ParthivBasu: Yes, the base change argument is the correct one. Hmmm meanwhile I think that Lui refers by 2.6 only to the argumentation technique used in the proof of lemma 2.6. Otherwise I don't know why he really need the statment of 2.6 ***as such*** to settle $X_{\bar{k}} $ blabla implies $X_{K}$ blabla...